# Contour integration and Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, contour-integration, distribution-theory, greens-function

I have a question which is related to changing an improper integral into a contour integral that 'looks' similar, but is not the same. The author (D.H. Griffel) says that it is 'right' to do it, but I don't understand why. It appears this is related to the standard thesis in the use of Green's functions. The author and I want to 'solve' the PDE
$$
u_{tt} - \nabla^2 u = f.
$$
The author rewrites the problem as
$$
(\partial_t ^2 - \nabla_x^2) w(\vec{x},t;\vec{y},s) = \delta(x-y) \delta(t-s).
$$
By using the Fourier transform he finds
$$
-(\omega^2 - |\vec{k}|^2) v = e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{y} - \omega s)}
$$
with $v$ being the Fourier transform of $w$. Now the question of contour integration arises. The author says that
$$
w(\vec{x},t;\vec{y},s) = \frac{1}{4 \pi^3 |\vec{y} - \vec{x}|} \int_{0}^\infty k \sin k |\vec{y} - \vec{x}| I(k)\,  \, dk
$$
with
$$
I(k) = \int_{- \infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\omega(s-t)}}{k^2 - \omega^2} d\omega.
$$
The author can't evaluate this integral because it has poles at $\omega = \pm k$. Instead, the author evaluates different contour integral that avoids the poles and is closed in the upper- or lower half-plane.

[image: Contour integral]

But my 'gripe' is that these integrals are not the same integral as $I(k)$. The author says that each choice of integration contour corresponds to a different $w$. My question:

- Why is it relevant to look at these alternative integral contours; after all, we're not interested in them. I can't see a reason why they are related to the integral we want to determine that would give us $w$. Is this anecdotal, or something rigorous?
- How can the author prove that each choice of contour corresponds to different boundary conditions?

---

What do I mean by 'the integrals are not the same':

- $I(k)$ is not a complex number for almost any $k$ (in the sense of lebesgue or riemann)
- The integral of the integrand of $I$ over a contour avoiding the poles is a complex number (in the sense of riemann).

---

In the case so-called $i \varepsilon$-prescription is something mathematical, it would be great if you could provide a reference to the theorem, or just post the theorem and idea for the proof here.

Comment: What do you mean by, the integrals aren't exactly the same as $I(k)$ ? It could mean a couple different things and I don't want to address something you're not confused about.

Comment: Thanks, I have written what I think I mean by that. Please see what you can make of it

Comment: Yes you are correct. The integral $I(k)$ is not a standard integral and it simply does not exist as a Riemann integral. This is why you need a so-called $i\epsilon$-prescription to make sense out of it that way. This is quite common for many Fourier type integrals. The good thing is that we can extend the Fourier transform to apply to a broader class of functions and make sense of these type of integrals, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions

Comment: @Winther Thanks. I know about tempered distributions, though I should say I am not a professor in the field of tempered distributions. I am only a phd student of applied math. Could you show me the relevant theorem that explains why some of these alternative contours are even vaguely related to the integral that we should evaluate to get $w$? I guess, could you show the $i \varepsilon$-theorems you have in mind, such that I can see that this alternative integral gives something that solves the problem in the sense of Green?

Comment: A couple points to make: One $k$ is the radial coordinate of the full Fourier variable, so it can only be positive (one could, however, use an even symmetry argument to extend the integral). Second, the wave equation is open minded in terms of time flow. From memory a long time ago, one pole (probably the RHS pole) corresponds to the retarded (causal) Green operator (propagator) and the other corresponds to the advanced (anticausal) propagator. As for the values of $I(k)$, having not done the integral I can't say whether or not the complex value is justified.

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi I have heard these pictorial things before and read them in every book i own about green's function, but I have not seen proof that explains why these alternative contours are related to $w$.

Comment: When you finish the integral, eventually you will find that the choice in pole will change whether or not the delta in the Greens function says $\delta(s-(t\mp |x-y|))$ in the end. You are making the assumption that $w$ has uniqueness when it does not. All four of these are valid greens functions, depending on which individual behavior you would like to analyze in your wave.

Answer (score 1):

Different $i\epsilon$ prescriptions in fact correspond to different boundary conditions on the Green function.

Your function $w$ is defined by a second order partial differential equation which does not completely specify it until boundary conditions are given. The different contours give you different functions which satisfy the same differential equation but have different homogeneous parts - they differ by solutions to the homogeneous differential equation and these parts parameterise the possible boundary conditions on your equation.

As pointed out in the comments, the integral is not well posed due to the poles and requires either a regularisation or modification to its definition. This could be done in some cases by using the Principal Value but there are other options such as deforming the contour to avoid the poles (these coincide for certain choice of contour).

Comment: Minor detail - in general the boundary conditions on w should be inherited from those on the function f, but these were not specified either and hence the solution space includes all such boundary conditions at this point

Comment: Could you show the iε-theorems you have in mind such that I can see that any of the prescriptions correcpond to a boundary condition?

Comment: The different boundary conditions are indicated by the $\pm$ subscripts - in physics we refer to them as "advanced" solutions (++) , "retarded" solutions (--) or Feynman propagators (mixed signs).

Comment: I have modified the question. I am asking for something mathematical. 'Cute' drawings (if I may say without causing offence) with plus and minus symbols and a good imagination doesn't help me in my phd thesis

Comment: Well you could try working out the difference between the solutions corresponding to different contours and show that this difference satisfies the homogeneous solution. See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator

Answer (score 0):

Finally, something I understand!

The basic idea is that all the information about a contour integral is encoded in its poles. This is why the solution to all sorts of integrals are determined by residues (which are just scaled line integrals around all poles within whatever contour you choose).

Now, for your question, the poles are located ON the contour, so the question we need to ask is whether or not the pole is inside or outside the contour of interest? It’s actually a trick question because a simple pole is “half-in, half out”. Try it! Manually compute the integral of a meromorphic function around the little deformation contour and as long as the pole is first order (simple), you will always get negative one half the expected residue.

So poles contain all the information, and your contour only contains half the pole, as the pole is “half-in, half-out”. This means you’re losing information, and if you solve whatever contour integral you want, this typically shows as a constraint on your solution. In order to avoid losing information, just take generate a second contour that covers the remaining half of the pole. You’ll find that the constraints on your integral then tell the full story.

In summary: Always use the full pole or you will lose information. If a pole is on the contour, generate as many instances of a contour as it takes to fully cover it. The restrictions on the solution are typically additive to the final solution.

I hope you found my answer useful